# Testing in app billing in alpha mode and cancel transaction

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have use Google in app billing in my android app,Currently my app is in Alpha test mode and i have published it.
When user Purchase an product then it ask for real credit card detail.Then i have enter my credit card detail and complete transaction for testing.Now i don't now how to revers that money in Customers account by which he purchases product.
I was found a post on stack overflow that mention that transaction can b canceled in Test mode.So Amount can be refunded in testing.

Have any idea.please help me in this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a testing email address on play store server. It will refund after 14 day in sandbox mode.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Thanks!

Comment: so it will automatically cancel all transaction.But what happen if i will Make this app live today.

Comment: I was facing the same issue.There is no way for test in sandbox mode like iOS.Another way you can refund manually from google wallet where you already set it up an account for application that amount will be credited.

Comment: can you please provide me link from where i can manually refund amount.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762370/does-google-play-in-app-billing-version-3-support-refunds this can help

Comment: link that you provide is by code,is there any process form developers account so i can cancel transaction from there.

Comment: I have not found any other way for Refund Amount to customer so i am accepting your answer.Thanks for your support.

Comment: Thanks.I will provide you link if i will found. One more thing you can go on google wallet admin panel of developer account.I think there should be option for that.