# How to detect canceled or refunded order for Google in-app billing?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-checkout

I have red a lot of posts and Google documents, but am still not clear how to tell an in-app purchase has been refunded. I have red carefully [In-App Billing v3 - Don't detect refund](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861625/in-app-billing-v3-dont-detect-refund) and [Does Google Play In-App Billing Version 3 support refunds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762370/does-google-play-in-app-billing-version-3-support-refunds).

I believe that I took the following notes from an official Google document a while ago by copy & paste:

> purchaseState:    The purchase state of the order. Possible values are 0
>   (purchased), 1 (canceled), or 2 (refunded).

Now, [the official document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) has the following:

-> purchaseState:   The purchase state of the order. It always returns 0-

> (purchased).

More specifically, if an IAB purchase is refunded or canceled, is that still in the user's inventory obtained by mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener)?
If so, how can one tell the purchase has been canceled or refunded?

Update [2019-12-12]:

I have tested many times and confirmed the following:

If an order is canceled after refunding, it will disappear from the results returned by [getPurchasesList](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.PurchasesResult.html#getPurchasesList()).  The time it takes for this to happen varies.  It could be minutes to over 10 hours. I think this depends on when Google Play refreshes its cache. It seems that one can open Google Play to refresh its cache. In one case, [getPurchasesList](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.PurchasesResult.html#getPurchasesList()) still returned a refunded purchase more than 10 hours after refunding, but it stopped returning it as soon as Google Play is opened.

Comment: Did you ever get any more info on this? After refunding an order I still see purchaseState as 0.

Comment: @Flyview No unfortunately.  I think one way to deal with this is downloading all the voided orders to your own server, then check the order number against the data.  https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases  It is quite some work. I  have not done it yet.

Comment: That's so strange. Why can't they just make it automatic like they do for subscriptions and just not return that the user has that purchase?

Comment: @Flyview  I remember that Google offers downloading  all orders, but I am unable to find the API now.  I will ask them tomorrow.   There are quite some fake IAB purchases (check out this  video among many hacks: https://youtu.be/3Zww3s8_A5g). Checking against the downloaded transactions would be a way to deal with these fake purchases.

Comment: Did you ever figure a way to do this without needing server-side / API approach? I just asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027898/honouring-in-app-purchases-offline-removing-cancelled-purchases

Comment: @JosephMcDermott Have you noticed my Update [2019-12-12]?  That is sufficient for me.

Comment: I did thank you @Hong, but still have questions :) I am going into Google Play Console and clicking 'refund' where I have the option to 'revoke' or not. Whether or not I revoke, I still get the purchase coming in purchasesList (even after 24 hours). The only way I have found to get a meaningful response from Google is to call acknowledgePurchase() to get a "Item is not owned by the user" result, however the docs clearly state to only acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged, so feel like I shouldn't be calling acknowledgePurchase() over and over again...

Comment: @Hong I take it back... it has literally just this second disappeared when I tried again! I think it was from opening Google Play App and refreshing the "My Apps" screen. OK looking good now, the items I marked as 'revoke' are NOT in the purchaseList, whereas the items marked as 'dont revoke' are still active purchases, which makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JosephMcDermott The cache problem of Google Play has been a chronic headache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked out the voided purchase list API? It returns a list of cancelled, refunded or charged-back purchases.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/voidedpurchases/list

Answer (score -4):

Scrape the Google Console. That's what I do.